# Regular expression to find a line containing certain characters and remove that line

Tags: regex

I have text file which has lot of character entries one line after another.
I want to find all lines which start with `::` and delete all those lines.

What is the regular expression to do this?

-AD

Comment: Which programming language are working with?

Answer (score 8):

Regular expressions don't "do" anything. They only match text.

What you want is some tools that uses regular expressions to identify a line and then apply some command to those tools.

One such tools is `sed` (there's also `awk` and many others). You'd use it like this:

```
sed -e "/^::/d" < input.txt > output.txt
```

The part "`/^::/`" tells `sed` to apply the following command to all lines that start with "::" and "`d`" simply means "delete that line".

Or the simplest solution (which my brain didn't produce for some strange reason):

```
grep -v "^::" input.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: I think you have forgotten the Regex.Replace function...  That actually "does" something, doesn't it?

Comment: @Dcoduc: as you said: The function does something (its one of the tools I mentioned). The regular expression itself still only matches some text. It's the semantics of the function that defines what is to be done with the matched text.

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -i -e '/^::/d' yourfile.txt
```

Comment: I think this is perhaps the best answer, but it might be worth mentioning that not all versions of sed have a -i option.

Answer (score 1):

```
^::.*[\r\n]*
```

If you're reading the file line-by-line you won't need the `[\r\n]*` part.

Answer (score 0):

Simple as:

```
^::
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have sed or grep, find this and replace with empty string:

```
^::.*[\r\n]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the pointers:

Following thing worked for me. After "**::**" any character was possiblly present in the text file so i gave:

^::[a-zA-Z0-9 I put all punctuation symbols here]*$

-AD

Comment: you don't need to match enything after the initial ^::

In your example you are forced to "account for" all the characters because you put a $ at the end.

Comment: If he's using a line-oriented tool like grep you're right. But he still hasn't said.

Comment: @goldenmean, what's preventing you from using .* instead of that monster character class?

Comment: I agree, it would be probably better to use a singleline option and add the .* to the expression.

Comment: Single-line? Why would you want the dot to match newline characters? If you read one line at a time, there won't be any newlines to match, and if you read the whole file into memory before processing, the dot-star will consume the rest of the file the first time it's applied.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my contribution in C#:

Text stream:

```
string stream = :: This is a comment line
```

Syntax:

```
Regex commentsExp = new Regex("^::.*", RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(commentsExp.Replace(stream, string.Empty));
```

Alternatively, if I wanted to simply take a text file that included comments and produce an exact duplicate without the comment lines I could use a simple but effective combination of the type and findstr commandline tools:

```
type commented.txt | findstr /v /R "^::" > uncommented.txt
```